# Changing order of the elements in javascript object according to given key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to change the order of the Object in javascript by given key. Here is my code for the same but it says "shift is not a function". Is it not applicable on objects? Please give a solution.

```
    periods = {
      "Su": 6,
      "Mo": 10,
      "Ma": 7,
      "Ra": 18,
      "Ju": 16,
      "Sa": 19,
      "Me": 17,
      "Ke": 7,
      "Ve": 20,
    };
    rotateOrder(key:any, entities:any) {
            let result = entities;
            for(var k in entities) {
              if(entities.hasOwnProperty(k) && k != key){
                result.push(result.shift());
              }
              else {
                return result;
              }
            }
          }
console.log(this.rotateOrder("Ve", this.periods));
```

Comment: shift doesn't work with object

Comment: Is there any other way to do shifting for objects?

Comment: convert to array with for example Object.entries()

Comment: If order is important then consider a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` to transform an object into an array, then use `.slice()` and `.concat()`, and finally `Object.fromEntries()` to get back your object.

In the example below, I also used `Object.keys()` and `.indexOf()` to find the index of `key`, but there are other solutions.

```js
let periods = {
  "Su": 6,
  "Mo": 10,
  "Ma": 7,
  "Ra": 18,
  "Ju": 16,
  "Sa": 19,
  "Me": 17,
  "Ke": 7,
  "Ve": 20,
};

function rotateOrder(key, obj) {
  let idx = Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key) // find the index of your key
  let arr = Object.entries(obj)  // this transform your object into an array

  let newObj = Object.fromEntries( // this will recreate your object
    arr.slice(idx) // get the ending part of the array, starting on key
      .concat(arr.slice(0,idx)) // concatenate the beginning
    )
  return newObj
}

console.log(rotateOrder('Ju',periods))
```

You can also use `unshift` (with spread operator) instead of `concat`. I don't know which one performs better:

```
function rotateOrder(key, obj) {
  let idx = Object.keys(periods).indexOf(key) // find the index of your key
  let arr = Object.entries(periods)  // this transform your object into an array

  // move the ending part (starting from key) to the beginning
  arr.unshift(...arr.splice(idx)) 

  let newObj = Object.fromEntries(arr) // this will recreate your object
  return newObj
}
```

---

Note from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> Since ECMAScript 2015, objects do preserve creation order for string
>   and Symbol keys. In JavaScript engines that comply with the ECMAScript
>   2015 spec, iterating over an object with only string keys will yield
>   the keys in order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

We can re-arrange / change the array by using **object.entries and sort function**  :

**Code:**

```js
 let periods = {
      "Su": 6,
      "Mo": 10,
      "Ma": 7,
      "Ra": 18,
      "Ju": 16,
      "Sa": 19,
      "Me": 17,
      "Ke": 7,
      "Ve": 20,
    };

    let keysSorted = Object.entries(periods).sort(function (a, b) {
      return a[1] - b[1]
    })
    console.log(keysSorted);
```